# How to align to right on the same column in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have 2 text view and i want them to align horizontally at the same column. I tried to    `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textName"` but it seem like it goes to the bottom instead beside the `textName`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uQJv.png)

Expected output:
The `MovieDate` should align beside the `MovieName`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY1Uv.png)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/candy" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textName"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Movie Name"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textdate"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Movie Date"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textName"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your code, XML!

Answer (score 0):

`layout_toRightOf` is an `RelativeLayout` param, it is no-op set for child of `LinearLayout`, so you can safely remove tihs line, it does nothing...

`LinearLayout` which is a parent of both `TextView`s should have set `android:orientation="horizontal"`, thats for shure... but I see a lot of problems and potential improvements in your code, so maybe you should also set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for this `LinearLayout` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` for outer one (first child of `CardView`), also remove `android:layout_weight="2"`, its unnecessary as this layout have `match_parent` width

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/candy" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textName"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Movie Name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textdate"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Movie Date"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout and set orientation to horizontal instead . See this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android: orientation="horizontal" 
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Movie Name"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Movie Date"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout_weight attribute with value of 50 gives equal portions to each children i.e 50% each

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout is the easiest solution in my opinion, but you could also try ConstraintLayout.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/candy"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textName"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textName"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Movie Name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textdate"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageview"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textdate"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                android:text="Movie Date"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textName"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple **LinearLayout** you can use single **ConstraintLayout** and achieve same goal. Here is the modified code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/candy" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textName"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Movie Name"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageview"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageview"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textdate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Movie Date"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textName"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textName"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// instead of Linearlayout use RelativeLayout and remove layout gravity.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textName"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Movie Name"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textdate"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textName"
                android:text="Movie Date"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textSize="15sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```